# Convertir de un objeto a otro

Tags: spring, spring-boot

estoy haciendo una aplicación que tiene tanto parte back como parte front. La cosa es que en el back tengo dos objetos iguales (solo varía un campo) y uno es el que guardo en la base de datos y otro el que me envía el front.

**Estos serían mis objetos:**

```
public class UsuarioMongo {
    private String username;
    private Binary avatar;
    private String pass;
}

publc class UsuarioFront {
    private String username;
    private byte[] avatar;
    private String pass;
}
```

Estos modelos están sujetos a cambios y por eso necesito algún método de convertir un objeto al otro y luego aparte transformar la imagen. Actualmente lo tengo como un constructor donde pongo uno a uno todos los campos que me mandan pero claro, cada vez que se añadiese un campo al modelo habría que tocar el código y es algo que me gustaría evitar.

Para que se hagan una idea de lo que busco sería algo como esto (no se si se pueda con un objectMapper):

```
ObjectMapper obMapper = new ObjectMapper();
UsuarioMongo usuarioMongo = obMapper.algunMetodoEspecifico(usuarioFront);
usuarioMongo.setAvatar(new Binary(usuarioFront.getAvatar()));
```

Así por muchos campos que se le añadan mientras estén en los dos modelos no haría falta tocar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo utilizo en estos casos es la librería [remap](https://github.com/remondis-it/remap) y otra alternativa que he utilizado es [modelmapper](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application), con estas librerias puedes convertir los objetos de la forma en que necesitas.

Te dejo un ejemplo con tus entidades:

```
import com.remondis.remap.Mapper;
import com.remondis.remap.Mapping;

public class ConvertionTest {

    private static Mapper<UsuarioFront, UsuarioMongo> to;
    private static Mapper<UsuarioMongo, UsuarioFront> from;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        to = Mapping.from(UsuarioFront.class).to(UsuarioMongo.class)
                // Con esta propiedad omitimos todos los campos que no sean comunes entre Front y Mongo
                .omitOtherSourceProperties()
                // aqui omitimos el campo que es del mismo nombre pero de diferente tipo de datos
                .omitInDestination(UsuarioMongo::getAvatar)
                .mapper();

        from = Mapping.from(UsuarioMongo.class).to(UsuarioFront.class)
                // Con esta propiedad omitimos todos los campos que no sean comunes entre Mongo y Front
                .omitOtherDestinationProperties()
                .omitInSource(UsuarioMongo::getAvatar)
                .mapper();

        UsuarioFront front = new UsuarioFront();
        front.setAvatar("java".getBytes());
        front.setPass("clave");
        front.setUsername("Java");

        // Ejemplo de conversion de Front a Mongo
        UsuarioMongo mongo = to.map(front);
        System.out.println(mongo);

        // Ejemplo de conversion de Mongo a Front
        UsuarioFront conf = from.map(mongo);
        System.out.println(conf);
    }
}
// Salida de consola
UsuarioMongo{username='Java', avatar=null, pass='clave'}
UsuarioFront{username='Java', avatar=null, pass='clave'}
```

Se que se puede colar un converso propio para convertir el campo avatar caundo no son del mismo tipo, si encuentro ese caso actualizo la respuesta.

Si es valida la respuesta ayuda marcandola como correcta.

Comment: Que importación estás usando? A mi me sale este error al pegar ese código The method from(Class<UsuarioFront>) is undefined for the type Mapping. La importación que tengo yo es esta: import org.modelmapper.spi.Mapping;

Comment: Para utilizar modelmapper es import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

Comment: y si estas usando `remap import com.remondis.remap.Mapper; import com.remondis.remap.Mapping;`

Answer (score 1):

Es natural que si necesitas mas campos tengas que actualizar los modelos en tu codigo, ya que la idea de estos no es ser dinamicos si no servir de "modelos" a la aplicacion a la hora de transportar datos.

En cuanto a la conversion de los objetos, podrias crear un constructor a un objeto que reciba como parametro el otro para crearse, tal que asi.

```
UsuarioMongo(UsuarioFront front){
     this.username = front.getUsername();
     this.pass = front.getPass();
     this.avatar = new Binary(front.getAvatar());
}
```

Para que asi lo puedas llamar

```
UsuarioMongo mongo = new UsuarioMongo(usuarioFront);
```